# Fetching the matching & non matching records in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**Table: Student**

```
EmpId   Name   Course     Area    
--------------------------------
E001    John    Maths     USA
E001    John    Maths     LONDON
E001    John    English   LONDON
E001    John    English   GERMANY
E002    PETER   Maths     USA
E002    PETER   Maths     LONDON
E002    PETER   English   LONDON
E002    PETER   SCIENCE   GERMANY
```

**Table: Subject**

```
Course     Area
--------------------
Maths     USA
Maths     LONDON
English   GERMANY
ACCOUNTS  FRANCE
```

I need to Compare these two tables based on Course and Area, I need the records which are matching also Non-matching records from `STUDENT` and `COURSE` table.
Appreciate your help and effort in this.

**Sample output:**

```
E001    John    Maths     USA
E001    John    Maths     LONDON
E001    John    English   LONDON
E001    John    English   GERMANY
null    null    ACCOUNTS  FRANCE
E002    PETER   Maths     USA
E002    PETER   Maths     LONDON
E002    PETER   English   LONDON
E002    PETER   SCIENCE   GERMANY
null    null    ACCOUNTS  FRANCE
```

Thank you

Comment: `I need the records which are matching also Nonmatching records` Can you provide the sample output?

Comment: Hi please check my query, i have ammended my required output

Answer (score 0):

```
-- students with matching areas
select s.EmpId, s.name, a.course, a.area
  from student s
  inner join subject a
    on (a.course = s.course and a.area = s.area)
union all
-- areas without matching students
select s.EmpId, s.name, a.course, a.area
  from subject a
  left outer join student s
    on (s.course = a.course and s.area = a.area)
 where s.EmpId is null;
```

Could you please explain, why you expect the rows

```
E002    PETER   English   LONDON
E002    PETER   SCIENCE   GERMANY
```

in your result list?

And why do you expect the row

```
null    null    ACCOUNTS  FRANCE
```

twice?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the query . Am having another output scenario(Please check my output). Could you provide me the solution

Comment: Hi Rams, i have adjusted my query. I don't know the sense of this query but here it is. Results of students not matching to an area are no longer included.

Comment: Adjusted table names as well

Comment: Hi frank, Am using oracle. so left inner join wont support

Comment: Could you please answer my questions above, because i don't understand these results